# Factoring cubic equation

Tags: factoring

Trying to understand this passage where this:

$$\left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)\left[\left(\frac{2}{3}\beta-I\right)^2 -\frac{1}{8}\beta^2-\frac{1}{4}\beta\left(\frac{2}{3}\beta-I\right)\right]=0$$

gets factored into this:

$$\left(\frac{1}{6}\beta-I\right) \left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right) \left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)=0$$

I is a real variable and $\beta$ is a constant. What method is used to achieve this factorization?

Comment: Note that the leading term in the first line matches two of the factors in the second.  The thing inside the square brackets is a quadratic which matches the other two factors in the second.  You can just expand the terms inside the square brackets and use the quadratic formula.

Comment: You present things in a too complicated way. Your question should be : why is $\left(\frac{2}{3}\beta-I\right)^2 -\frac{1}{8}\beta^2-\frac{1}{4}\beta\left(\frac{2}{3}\beta-I\right)=0$ equivalent to $\left(\frac{1}{6}\beta-I\right) \left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)=0$ !

Comment: What's inside the square brackets is of the form $\,a^2 - a b - 2 b^2\,$. Just factor that quadratic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have by expanding and simplifying

$$\left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)\left[\left(\frac{2}{3}\beta-I\right)^2 -\frac{1}{8}\beta^2-\frac{1}{4}\beta\left(\frac{2}{3}\beta-I\right)\right]$$
$$=\left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)\left[\frac{4}{9}\beta^2-\frac{4}{3}\beta I+I^2-\frac{1}{8}\beta^2-\frac{1}{6}\beta^2+\frac{1}{4}\beta I\right]$$
$$=\left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)\left[\frac{11}{72}\beta^2-\frac{13}{12}\beta I+I^2\right]$$
$$=\left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)\left[\frac{11}{72}\beta^2-\frac{1}{6}\beta I-\frac{11}{12}\beta I +I^2\right]$$
$$\left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)\left[\frac{1}{6}\beta\left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)-I\left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)\right]$$
$$=\left(\frac{1}{6}\beta-I\right)\left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)\left(\frac{11}{12}\beta-I\right)$$